# How to build Virtual Raster using grouped DEM layers as input with QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, virtual-raster

I have compiled about 700 DEM tiles (each in its own layer) for some islands. I would like to create a virtual raster for each island. I grouped the DEM layers by the island name in the layer panel. But when I try to choose input layers, the groups are not available to choose from and I am forced to choose from the original 700 layers. Is there a workaround for this or a clever way to export the layers within the group so I can load them as files?

Comment: How did you "group" the layers - in the layers panel?

Comment: Yes, in the layers panel.

Comment: What you want to create is a virtual raster - a virtual "layer" is something completely different, it applies for vector data only. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Adding to my answer: maybe there is an option using Python. I can't help you in this.  But probably you have more chances to get an answer to this if you ask a new question that focuses on that aspect: is it possible to access layer groups from the layer panel with python? Be aware that questions concerning python, it is normally expected that you already have some code and can show what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit but I don't know where I implied vector. Also, I did not intend to ask about python, although it may be doing the heavy lifting in the background, I am using the menus in QGIS 3 and have no code to show. I simply thought the menus had some option I overlooked. I was hoping the layer group was sufficient to filter the input of the dialog box rather than plucking them one by one from the 700 files in the project. I was asking if it possible to do with layer groups.

Comment: You asked about "virtual layers": these are dynamically created layers based on SQL query, similar to a database view: thus always vectors, not rasters - virtual layers and virtual rasters are completely different things, see: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?highlight=virtual%20layers#creating-virtual-layers. I'm sorry that I can't present you a better answer. As far as I know, unfortunately there is no way using tools accessible by menus only - but maybe, I overlooked something.

Comment: I don't see 'virtual layer' anywhere in my question. My original question was "QGIS 3. Build Virtual Raster using grouped layers as input?" before it was edited. I never mentioned SQL or vector data.

Comment: Original title was: "QGIS 3. Build Virtual Layer using grouped layers as input?" - I edited it to virtual raster, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8d2c.png

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake that you fixed 1 hour after it was posted so it was obvious to you that I meant raster all along so why mention SQL and vector and all that other stuff when you already knew what I meant?

Comment: Sorry if my tone seemed lecturing. I was simply not sure if you are aware of this difference and also it might be confusing for others trying to find a solution. I only insisted explaining because you asked where you mentioned vectors. So everything is allright, I hope :-)

Comment: You bet, all good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `Build virtual raster` in batch mode and than define a pattern as for which layers or files you want to use. If your raster layers already have in their name some characteristics that allow you to group them together based on that, it's going to be easy. Often, DEM files are named after the extent/area they are located - something like `gt30e140n90` for example.

If not, it's going to be more difficult as you don't have an easy way to access the groups you created in the layer panel, e.g. via QGIS expressions. They seem to be pure visualization tools to organize the layer structure. So you must use a workaround. I see two (probably three) possibilities:

1. Rename all layers by adding for expample a prefix that represents the group - like `1_` for group 1, `2_`for group 2 etc. As an alternative, you could also save all the layers from the same group to an own folder. Than you are able to run the tool to build a virtual raster in batch mode and select a pattern for the layer- or filename, using autofill/Fill down, as described here: https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/advanced-qgis.html#batch-processing, but using expressions to define the layer-/file-name pattern to select the ones you want to use.
2. Save a copy of your project. Than delete all but one group. Create a virtual raster of all layers left in the project. Than re-open the saved original project, repeat steps 2 and 3. This might be the most time-consuming option I see: not very elegant, but efficient.
3. Using [map themes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#map-themes) instead of groups. I did not test it and I am not sure if it is going to work, just to give you an idea: define each group as map theme. Toggle visibility so that you see only one group, than create a new map theme. Repeat for all groups. Creat a Model using [Model builder/Graphic modeler](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html?highlight=model%20builder). There, you have the possibility to set map themes as input.

Comment: Map themes at least can be accessed in the Model Builder, so there might be a way. Maybe ask a focused question here if/how it is possible to use map themes for what you want to achieve. Another possibility would be:1.  Save a copy of your project. 2. delete all but one group 3. Create virtual raster of all layers left in the project 4. re-open the saved original project, repeat steps 2 and 3. This might be the most time-consuming option I see, but it's more a workaround than an elegant solution.

Comment: Sorry, I posted to soon and Stack Exchange timed out my edit. So I deleted it.

Comment: That most recent suggestion is what I will do. It preserves the groups and the project itself is throw away once I get each island exported as its on DEM. BTW I noticed this and thought it might be useful: Right click the group and choose 'Copy Group' paste that into a text editor and get an XML listing of every detail of every file in that group. Sort the lines and pull out the path to each file in the group. Useful for scripting I guess but I did not know all that XML was lurking below the surface.

Comment: Hope that this will work for you - indeed an interesting question, I hope there would be a better way. I included this last proposal in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of user @lejedi76 in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385905/88814), there is a somewhat more elegant solution to your problem. It consists of the idea to use the variable `@map_layers` that returns a list of all visible layers:

1. Toggle visibility for just one group of layers, than run `create virtual raster` in batch mode.
2. For `input layers`, use `Autofill / Calculate by Expression…` and paste this expression (see below for an alternative):

```
array_foreach (
    generate_series(
        0,
        array_length (
            array_first (
                array ( 
                    @map_layers  
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    layer_property ( 
        array_get (
            @map_layers , 
            @element
        ),
        'name'
    )
)
```

Now, all the visible rasters are selected as input and you can run the tool. Just set another group to be visible and do the same again. You might even create a model to shortcut all the manual work.

**Remark:** I got the impression that using the expression to select visible layers as input can behave quite buggy. Sometimes it works, sometimes not (that's why I asked the question linked above). After several testing, each time restarting QGIS, I have the impression that the above expression works better than the one that follows. I'm still not sure about the cause (might have to do with a conflict with a plugin installed?). What could help: first select manually a few input layers, than de-select them (without running the tool). Afterwards use the expression for selecting input layers.

PS:
As an alternative expression for step 2, this much simpler expression (tribute to @lejedi76) should also work. I managed it to run, however, in my configuration it works less reliable.

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach ( 
    @map_layers,
    layer_property(@element,'name')
  )
)
```