# Showing the name of certain visible layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża. In my project, I have four layers and I need to show in the print composer **the name** of those that are visible, but only among the first three (I don't want to get the name of the fourth one that is always visible). The expression proposed in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385900/automatically-create-an-array-of-all-visible-layer-names-in-qgis) works well but it returns all visible layers (which is not what I want):

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach ( 
   @map_layers,
   layer_property(@element,'name')
  )
)
```

To create the array of layers I'm interested in, I've tried the following

```
array_to_string(
  array_foreach ( 
   array (layer1, layer2, layer3),
   layer_property(@element,'name')
  )
)
```

But it returns the name of all layers in the new array, no matter if they're visible or not. I guess I need to use the `is_layer_visible` function, but all my attempts have failed. How should it be written?

Comment: Try with the `@map_layers_ids` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Use [`is_layer_visible()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-layer-visible) with another `array_foreach()` function:

```
array_foreach (
    array_foreach (@map_layers,layer_property (@element,'name')),
    if (
        is_layer_visible(@element),
        @element,
        ''
    )
)
```

However, be aware of the fact that `is_layer_visible()` is only available in some contexts, see the comments to [QGIS expression function is_layer_visible() missing in QGIS 3.28](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446911/qgis-expression-function-is-layer-visible-missing-in-qgis-3-28) and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51135).

Comment: Mmmm... I'm doing something wrong. If I use this expression as it is, it returns an empty string or, if I wrap it up in an `array_to_string` function, it returns "true, true".

Comment: Yes, the expression returns true/false. What should the expression achieve?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see my question wasn't clear enough. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Don't have access to QGIS right now, but hope it works like this: see edited answer

Comment: Back to another machine, right now I can't test the expression, since the function `is_layer_visible()` is missing... see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446911/qgis-expression-function-is-layer-visible-missing-in-qgis-3-28

Comment: `is_layer_visible()` is only available in certain contexts - but where it is available, the solution should work.