# What is expression for displaying what layer group within table of contents is selected in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, expression

I am building a query for a text box in a print composer template. I have a group of historical imagery WMS layers whose names correspond to historical imagery for a certain year i.e. '1983 Historical Imagery'. I would like that text box to display which layer (and hence year) is currently switched on (assuming one is only ever turned on at a time). I would like the query to include only layers within the that particular group which are turned on.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/446850/128665

Comment: Yes, thank you, however when I try even the most basic 'is_layer_visible('1983 Historical Imagery'), it still returns a 'false' response despite the layer clearly being on and the case exactly matching the layer. I've also tried dragging a layer into a blank .qgis file, and trying the command and it still yields a 'false' response.